# Sort only even numbers in array and do not touch odds

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have an array of integers and the exercise tells me to sort only even elements. I understand this can be easily achieved by plain checking each element, which is probably O(n^2).
What I am trying to do is to write a comparator which takes only even numbers as parameters and then sort the whole array with it.

```
Comparator<Integer> comp = new Comparator<>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    };
Arrays.sort(array, comp));
```

Is there any way to do so?
Thank you

Comment: Odd numbers should stay at their index?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Yes, that's right

Comment: I would really go for a custom bubble/insertion sort in the case rather than using comparator and an utilized `sort` method.

Comment: @dbl I'm not sure I'd have a custom sort, rather, I'd extract the evens, sort them using an inbuilt and then put them back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not try to create a `Comparator` like that. Seems more like hassle to achieve it. Instead you could split the array in odd and even numbers. 
Sort the even numbers and add the odd numbers to their previous position with [`ArrayList#add(index,number)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))

Comment: And to do so, you have to store indexes of odd numbers?

Comment: @Shved Keep the old list and iterate over it. Check for odd numbers and add that to the new sorted even list with the current index.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void sortEven(int[] inputArray) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i]%2== 0)
            list.add(inputArray[i]);
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i]%2== 0){
            inputArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(list.get(j).toString());
        j++;}
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(array, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a%2, b%2));
```

The above function sorts with custom comparison function which sorts only even numbers.